# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, x), found shape=(x)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am implementing a ConvNet to predict roundwins out of the minimap of a game. But I am having issues with training the Net.

when I runt the following code, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 312, 312, 3), found shape=(312, 312, 3)
```

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import relu
import numpy as np

#input layers
minimapInput = keras.Input(shape = (312, 312, 3), name="minimap_image")

#layers for mini input
mini = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(minimapInput)
mini = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(mini)
mini = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2)(mini)
mini = keras.layers.Flatten()(mini)
mini = keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu')(mini)
mini = keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(mini)
mini = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(mini)

#output
ctRoundWin = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=keras.activations.softmax)(mini)

#model
model = keras.Model(inputs=minimapInput, outputs=ctRoundWin)

#creating/reading train data
def readFrames(file, frames, width, height, depth=3):
    output = np.zeros((frames, height, width, depth))
    for frame in range(frames):
        for i in range(depth):
            for j in range(height):
                for k in range(width):
                    try:
                        output[frame, j, k, i] = ord(file.read(1)[0])  
                    except IndexError:
                        output[frame, j, k, i] = 0    
    return output

y_pred = np.zeros(167)
frames = 167
minifile = open("C:\\Users\\s-wel\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CSAI\\test\\mini.txt", "r")
mini = readFrames(minifile, frames, 312, 312)
minifile.close

#creating tf Dataset
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((mini, y_pred))

#running it
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics = keras.metrics.binary_accuracy)
model.fit(data, epochs=1)
```

all the other solutions I have found don't really fix this.

Comment: can you try ''shape = (,312, 312, 3)'' in keras.Input?

Comment: nope, that gives me a syntax error, and if I put (None, 312, 312, 3) it tells me it expects a ndim = 4 instead of ndim = 5 and i gave him (None, None, 312, 312, 3).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself, the problem was in the dataset i had created. I fixed it by removing the line

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((mini, y_pred))
```

and changing the last line to

```
model.fit([mini, left, right, score], y_pred)
```

Thanks for anyone who helped